# java.lang.IllegalStateException:getWritableDatabase called recursively

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

**Please help me to rsolve the error :**

```
D/AndroidRuntime(836): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(836): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.List}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.FirstProject.Database.onCreate(Database.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.FirstProject.List.onCreate(List.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  ... 11 more
```

**code:**

```
package com.example.FirstProject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class List extends ListActivity{
ListView stations;
protected int tn;
protected TextView source;
protected EditText searchText;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
protected Cursor cursor;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)throws IllegalStateException {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

       tn = getIntent().getIntExtra("tn", 0);
       SQLiteDatabase db = (new Database(this)).getReadableDatabase();
      // searchText = (EditText) findViewById (android.R.id.list);
        stations = (ListView) findViewById (android.R.id.list);


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT source._id,FROM tinfo WHERE city._id =     Mumbai", new String[]{});
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,  R.layout.screen2,  cursor, new     String[] {}, new int[] {});
        stations.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

}
```

Comment: Add your code and we might be able to help you.

Comment: hey friends i have added the code.Please check it out and tell me how to resolve that error...please help.

Comment: This is still not enough. We need the code of your `Database` class.

Comment: Leave it.I have changed the way of displaying data.

Answer (score 13):

You probably call `getWritableDatabase()`(or `getReadableDatabase()`) in one of the methods `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` of your implementation of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. `getWritableDatabase()` calls `onCreate`(or `onUpgrade`) so if you have a `getWritableDatabase()` call in one of those methods you will run in trouble.

Those methods have a parameter (a `SQLiteDatabase` object) that you must use to do your database logic(so you must NOT call `getWritableDatabase()` (or `getReadableDatabase()` in there).

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your code, but I suspect you're not calling SQLiteOpenHelper at the correct point in your startup.

It's OK to create your SQLiteOpenHelper object in onCreate(), but don't open the database until you need to read or write. In a content provider, the standard pattern is to create the
SQLiteOpenHelper in ContentProvider.onCreate(), but not call getWriteableDatabase() until
an access comes in.